# Replace double quotes inside style tag from HTML string to render correctly in DOM

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Given a HTML string like:

```
var str = "<span style="font-family: "Comic Sans MS"; font-size:10px">retesting font</span>"
```

I'd like to transform it to:

```
var str = "<span style="font-family:Comic Sans MS; font-size:10px">retesting font</span>"
```

In the above 1st line need to remove double quotes mentioned in font family so that it meets the expected result mentioned in second line and renders in DOM.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Note that Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You're expected to [try to solve your problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/5698098), and then ask a specific question based on your attempt (=code) explaining the difficulty you have. Also note that you didn't provide enough details preventing others from answering effectively, and correctly.

Comment: I've voted to reopen this question: However, stripping nested quotes within the css font-family property value will also break the correct font mapping i.e a font-family names including whitespace (e.g. "Open Sans") will always require some enclosure e.g.  single or escaped quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const str1 = `<span style="font-family: "Comic Sans MS"; font-size:10px">retesting font</span>`

const str2 = `<p><span style="font-family: "Arial Black", "Arial Bold", Gadget, sans-serif; font-size: 12pt;">Arjun</p>`

function convert(str) {
  return str.replace(/(?<!=)"(?!>)/g,"");
}

console.log(convert(str1));
console.log(convert(str2));
```

Comment: earlier provided replace(/(?<=family:)\s*"|"(?=; font)/g,"") seems to be not working in IE/EDGE

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this

```js
var str = '<span style="font-family: "Comic Sans MS"; font-size:10px">retesting font</span>"'

var newStr = str.replace('"Comic Sans MS"', 'Comic Sans MS');
console.log(newStr);
```

Comment: Comic Sans MS font will be dynamic, it can be  
font-family: "Arial Black", "Arial Bold", Gadget, sans-serif; at times

Answer (score 0):

You can do like that -

```
var str = '<span style="font-family: "Comic Sans MS"; font-size:10px">retesting font</span>';
var res = str.replace('"Comic Sans MS"', "Comic Sans MS");
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Comic Sans MS font will be dynamic, it can be font-family: "Arial Black", "Arial Bold", Gadget, sans-serif;

Comment: @rakeshgujjar, Pavlos Karalis solution is perfect for you